# Displaying an image in listview dynamically

Tags: android

I am displaying text1, image and text2 again in a listview. The image is related to text1. Not all the text1 contains image. So if text1 contains image it will display or else not.
When the image is existing then the text1,image and text2 are displaying well. But when the image is not there then the text2 is not displaying. Only the text1 is displaying in the list.
Where I went wrong? Help me regarding this....

My Code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
--
 ---
---
---
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(listItem.gettext1());
imageUrl = "http://server.com//folder/"+ ret.get(0);(ret.get(0) is the name of the image along with extension)
imView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);
drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(imageUrl);
imView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText(listItem.gettext2());

}


private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
try {
    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src-name");
    return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
        return null;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Lazy Loading Here, See Below Example for that, it may help you.

[Lazy Loading Listview](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Comment: ok i will go thru it...but before that please tell me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: first try above code, if it will not help you than tell me i will solve your whole problem.